# how to display the image at different tag of UIImageView randomly in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to resolve this.

I have placed UIView in UIViewController.Then in UIView inside 15 UImageView is placed and  given tag for each UIImageView from 1 to 15.

I have used the code as:

```
images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

    NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", images];
    NSLog(@"%@",dd);



    randomIndex1=arc4random() % images.count;
    selectedImage = [images objectAtIndex:randomIndex1]; //random selected image

    NSLog(@"%@",selectedImage);

    number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];


    randomNumber = arc4random() % number.count; //random selected number
    NSLog(@"%d",randomNumber);

    for (int i = 0; i <randomNumber; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", selectedImage);

        // _img.image = selectedImage;

        //cell.img.image=selectedImage;

    }
```

classname.h file

```
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIView *v1;

@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b1;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b2;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b3;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *b4;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b5;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b6;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b7;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b8;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b9;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b10;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b11;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b12;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b13;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b14;
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView  *b15;
```

As i got a image in  NSLog(@"%@", selectedImage);and  also NSLog(@"%d",randomNumber); Ex:Image-SelectedImage,5-randomNumber then 
5 times the image will displayed.
My question is ,how to display the image in different tag

means:i have already given 15 UIImageView in UIView

```
 img1-tag as 1
   img2-tag as 2
   ....


   img15 -tag as 15
```

So i need to display the image at different tag of imageview

Comment: where you used the `setimage` code, you try to  set the UIImage to UIView not UIImageview

Comment: According to the title, the mistake is that you set a UIImage to a UIView, but your code here doesn't show that part.

Comment: Get the `UIImageView` object using `UIImageView *imgView = [v1 viewWithTag:tag];`

Comment: i have edited the question.please check

Comment: can you upload some screenshot what you exactly want to achieve ?